# Confusing behavior on when to dereference the mutable reference

Tags: rust

I have a function that takes the mutable reference of the string and appends some text.

```rust
fn append_str(s: &mut String) {
    s.push_str(" hi");
}
```

Suppose I have a string.

```
let mut s: String = "hi".to_string();
```

If I create the mutable reference to `s` and pass it to `append_str`, it compiles without a problem.

```
let mut ss = &mut s;

append_str(&mut ss);
```

However, if I expliclty define `ss` with `&mut String`, it does not compile.

```
let ss: &mut String = &mut s;
append_str(&mut ss);
```

it shows following compiler error.

```
   |
80 |     let ss: &mut String = &mut s;
   |         -- help: consider changing this to be mutable: `mut ss`
81 |     append_str(&mut ss);
   |                ^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

One thing funny is that if I dereference it, then it works.

```
let ss: &mut String = &mut s;
append_str(&mut *ss); // OK
```

What is the reason that we have to explicitly dereference in this case?

One more question: Why do we have to specify `mut` to the reference if we want to pass it to the function?

```
let ss = &mut s;
append_str(&mut ss); // ERROR
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ss` is a reference already, so `&mut ss` gives you (mutable) reference to (mutable) reference; if you have `ss`, you should call `append_str` with it directly: `append_str(ss)`.

It is only when you incorrectly take a mutable reference to `ss`, you need to declare it as `mut ss`. The normal use case for something like that is to pass it to a function that actually accepts `x: &mut &mut String` and uses something like `*x = &mut some_other_string` to make `ss` refer to a different reference to string. In your case the "fixed" code with `mut` compiles because the compiler automatically dereferences the double-reference for you.